# Is there any Perl module that can keep me from adding `or die` to anything that can fail?

Tags: perl, error-handling, perl-module

I'm writing code that runs all sorts of external commands as well as various filesystem commands that can fail.

Is there any module that can save me the trouble of adding `or die` to anything that can fail?

I'd like to be able to wrap the following in something so that instead of:

```
mkdir $dirname or die "can't create directory $dirname";

system("some external command") or die "can run some external command";
```

I get:

```
some_wrapper_code {
    mkdir $dirname;

    system("some external command");
}
```

such that if `mkdir` fails it'll tell me that the failure was in `mkdir`, and if `system` fails it'll tell me that the failure was in `system`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yep. Check out [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autodie) from CPAN.

From the docs:

> The `autodie` pragma provides a convenient way to replace functions that normally return
>   false on failure with equivalents that throw an exception on failure.
>
> The `autodie` pragma has *lexical scope*, meaning that functions and subroutines altered with 
>   `autodie` will only change their behaviour until the end of the enclosing block, file, or 
>   `eval`.

Comment: And starting with Perl 5.10.1, autodie is included in the core.
http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5101delta.html#New-Modules-and-Pragmata